# assign static ip address on the server, or based on MAC address?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, voip, static-ip

For an Asterisk VoIP server, is there any technical advantage to setting a static IP address directly on the server, versus using DHCP and having the DHCP server (router) assign a static ip address for that server based on the MAC address for a NIC (for example)?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2):

### DHCP

#### Pros

- Single, unified file and machine to administer to change IPs
- You can simulate 'static IPs' by assigning specific IPs to specific MAC addresses
- Moving the clients to another networks works better

  - No subnet issues
  - No clashing IPs
- Have more complicated configurations

  - Push routes from DHCP server
  - Push router and gateway information from DHCP server
  - Easier multi-subnet routing
  - More room to grow in the future

#### Cons

- None that I can see

---

### Local Static IP

#### Pros

- If you don't have a DHCP server already set up, you can skip that hastle
- Quick and dirty

#### Cons

- Not having a centralized location for configurations, you could more easily create bad configurations

  - Clashing IPs
- Harder to move to another network

Comment: Absolutely correct!  Nowadays there are absolutely no reasons to use static IPs, except for the DHCP server itself (or a test lab with 5 computers) ;-)  Upvoted!